How to get fresh data in Next.js when using ISR
i am using next.js 15 , Now i am facing an issue suppose when i build my project there was 10 blogs , now i have added one blog more when i visit the site only last 10 blogs are there or even if make any change in my blogs i don't see any change when i go from one page to other , but once i hard refresh twice then i am getting fresh data. I don't want hard refresh. How to fix it.
import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";
    
    async function getPost() {
      const res = await fetch(
        "https://67585e5260576a194d10384b.mockapi.io/blogs",
        {
          next: {
            revalidate: 20,
          },
        }
      );
      const post = await res.json();
      return post;
    }
    async function page() {
      const posts = await getPost();
      return (
        <div>
          {posts.map((post) => (
            <div key={post.id}>
              <Link href={`/${post.id}`}>{post.title}</Link>
            </div>
          ))}
          <Link className="text-blue-500 font-weight underline" href="/">
            Home
          </Link>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default page;


Isn't that intended? First time page gets put in cache. Second time the revalidate time has passed, you receive a stale version while it's creating a new version in de background. Third load you see the newly cached page.

@Reyno- i tried multiple times go back and forth home page to blog but still i am getting only old data

I believe what's happening is that getPosts is executed only on the server side, so you only get the posts available when the initial request is received. I bet if you refresh then you'd get any new posts, so that's the first thing worth verifying.
If you want to avoid a page refresh, you'll need to add a mechanism for fetching data on the client side. The best solution IMO would be to use a library like SWR which will refetch the data in the background.
You can do the same thing with React state and effects though. Here's some example code (though it's not exact and I haven't tested it).
// getPosts.js
async function getPost() {
    const res = await fetch(
        "https://67585e5260576a194d10384b.mockapi.io/blogs",
        {
            next: {
                revalidate: 20,
            },
        }
    );
    const post = await res.json();
    return post;
}

// PostsList.js
'use client'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

function PostsList({ initialPosts }) {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState(initialPosts)
    useEffect(() => {
        // refetch the posts every 1 second
        const intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
            const newPosts = await getPost()
            setPosts(newPosts)
        }, 1000)

        // Clean up the listener when this component is removed
        return () => clearInterval(intervalId)

    }, [setPosts])

    return <>
        {
            posts.map((post) => (
                <div key={post.id}>
                    <Link href={`/${post.id}`}>{post.title}</Link>
                </div>
            ))
        }
    </>

}

// Page.js
import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";

async function page() {
    const posts = await getPost();
    return (
        <div>
            <PostsList initialPosts={posts} />
            <Link className="text-blue-500 font-weight underline" href="/">
                Home
            </Link>
        </div>
    );
}

export default page;



An important thing to flag here is that you'll need to split your code into multiple files because useEffect can only be used in files with the 'use client' directive

@ JuanCaicedo -- i don't want client side data fetching

I think it will be impossible to get live refreshing if you're not fetching on the client.
You could try leveraging ISR to see if the problem is that the next.js server is caching your stale data https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration

You mention navigating between pages client-side. That will not trigger another server-side request, instead next.js will do a client-side refresh to load the previously rendered page
